# How can I get the transaction indexes involving a particular address

Tags: transactions

If I want to work with a particular address, I need to know all the transaction indices/hashes that have inputs or outputs to/from that address. How can I find out those values assuming that I have the Bitcoin core installed and synced. Is there a command I can give that will return that information for a given address?

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin Core has no option to maintain an index of addresses, thus you cannot search by address or search for things related to an address.

Answer (score 0):

The command you're looking for is the [listunspent](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#listunspent) command, which lists the UTXOs in your wallet and gives out the txid and output index for each one.

Comment: That only works for wallet addresses. I want to look up addresses that are not in the wallet.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a program in Python3 that allows you to search any address on bitcoin core whether it belongs to your wallet or not.

Here is the github link:

https://github.com/ORP967/Bitcoin_Core_RPC_par_address

Let me know what you think and any improvements you might have.